# We wanna wrap [wrapping] within [word-wrap]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wrapping) - 626 questions

> For questions regarding text and content wrapping at or across container borders.

[word-wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-wrap) - 1019 questions

> the feature of continuing on a new line when a line is full, such that each line fits in the viewable window, allowing text to be read

The excerpts seem to be describing the same concept.  [word-wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-wrap) should be the master.

Comment: [tag:wrapping] includes *content* wrapping, which is similar to Android's [tag:wrap-content]. Is it really certain that this is only about word-wrap/text-related?

Comment: @AndrewT. Anecdotally it is. There's only 91 questions tagged both [wrapping]  and [android]

Comment: Yeah, we need to clean it up before we merge the tags

Comment: @AndrewT. would you mind adding a tag wiki for this tag? It just got synonymized with [tag:android-wrap-content] and currently has no tag wiki.

Comment: @double-beep done, not sure if it will be approved, but I have tried my best...

Answer (score 17):

Apart from those two, there are two other tags which probably should all be merged into a single [word-wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-wrap) tag:

- [textwrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/textwrapping) - method for fitting text into an area by moving any text that overflows its boundaries onto a new line
- [linewrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linewrap) - no wiki

All of these (4 of them) are related to word wrapping and having a single tag for them makes sense.